# View pager not showing new fragment after replace

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to add an onClick listener in my arraylist adapter that will open a fragment when it is click on. When I click on the button the original fragment disappears but the new fragment does not show up.

```
viewHolder.commentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
            CommentFragment commentFragment = new CommentFragment();

            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewPager , commentFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

My new Fragment

```
public class CommentFragment extends Fragment {
View v;
ImageView backArrow;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_fragment, container,false);

    backArrow = v.findViewById(R.id.backarrow);
    Log.i("inflated","Should be inflated");


    backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    });

    return v;


}
public CommentFragment() {
}
```

}